# Saving dynamic text box value to mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql

While creating an invoice system, I have the code to add or remove the text box and section it's working fine. Once I try to save the data to MySQL its not working. I tried to insert the JSON output.

[image]

it's the JSON output of `$_POST`

```
{"sectionName":{"1":"1","2":"2"},"productCode":{"1":{"1":"1","2":"2"},"2":{"1":"1","2":"2"}},"productName":{"1":{"1":"1","2":"2"},"2":{"1":"1","2":"2"}},"quantity":{"1":{"1":"1","2":"2"},"2":{"1":"1","2":"2"}},"price":{"1":{"1":"1","2":"2"},"2":{"1":"1","2":"2"}},"notes":"","userId":"123456","invoice_btn":"Save Invoice","subTotal":"6","taxRate":"","taxAmount":"","totalAftertax":"","amountPaid":"","amountDue":""}
```

I not getting any idea how to insert this data to mySQL

Answer (score 0):

can u provide ur sql field? like field name and type.
but if its data string and wanna insert it on single field, try wrap ur json with single quotes like

```
'{"sectionName":{"1":"1","2":"2"},"productCode":{"1":{"1":"1","2":"2"},"2":{"1":"1","2":"2"}},"productName":{"1":{"1":"1","2":"2"},"2":{"1":"1","2":"2"}},"quantity":{"1":{"1":"1","2":"2"},"2":{"1":"1","2":"2"}},"price":{"1":{"1":"1","2":"2"},"2":{"1":"1","2":"2"}},"notes":"","userId":"123456","invoice_btn":"Save Invoice","subTotal":"6","taxRate":"","taxAmount":"","totalAftertax":"","amountPaid":"","amountDue":""}'
```